# Magento 2 Change order of include/exclude tax

Tags: magento2, price

I'm trying to find the best way to change the order in which magento 2 displays the product(s) total for included and excluded tax. By default magento shows the price including tax, then the price excluding tax. But I want to swap that around so the price excluding tax is first and including tax is second.

I've managed to do this for the product page by changing the `final_price.phtml` file in my theme:

> Magento_Catalog\templates\product\price\final_price.phtml

by swapping around the span tags:

```
 <span class="old-price">
    <?php echo $block->renderAmount($priceModel->getAmount(), [
        'display_label'     => __('Regular Price'),
        'price_id'          => $block->getPriceId('old-price-' . $idSuffix),
        'price_type'        => 'oldPrice',
        'include_container' => true,
        'skip_adjustments'  => true
        ]); ?>
</span>

<span class="special-price">
    <?php echo $block->renderAmount($finalPriceModel->getAmount(), [
        'display_label'     => __('Special Price'),
        'price_id'          => $block->getPriceId('product-price-' . $idSuffix),
        'price_type'        => 'finalPrice',
        'include_container' => true,
        'schema' => $schema
    ]); ?> 
</span>
```

The problem is it still shows the default order in the mini-cart and checkout areas. Do I need to edit template files for cart and checkout too (and which ones), or is there a better way to change the order across the entire site, e.g **a layout, config setting somewhere or modification?**

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

I found the best solution for this was to use CSS instead of trying to adjust the core PHP and template files by setting display: flex for the parent element div container then setting order: css parameter to change the  price containers position.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can change order of include and exclude price from `default.phtml` file. 
 **please follow following path according to your theme path**

```
public_html/app/design/frontend/ogani/ogani_default/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/price/amount/default.phtml
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I've altered the file 'public_html/app/design/frontend/Smartwave/porto/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/price/amount/default.phtml' and it's worked for the product and categories page, but the minicart and checkout still show them in the wrong order. Is there somewhere else I need to change them for the checkout and mini cart?

Comment: What exactly did you change in `default.phtml` to change the order? I only see one `<span>` and then the Adjustments block. Moving the Adjustments block just moves the Excl. block. But I want the Excl. price displayed as regular and the Incl. price in the Adjustments block.